# What are the default values for opening links in WSL?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On a fresh WSL install, when running

- `open .` : Windows File Explorer will open
- `open https://example.com`: My default Windows browser in will open.

However, I believe after I installed Lynx, this behavior changed and Lynx set itself as the default app for opening links/paths.

What were these defaults originally on Ubuntu WSL, and how can I restore them?

Comment: The default browser for Ubuntu is Firefox and the latest version of Ubuntu always comes with the latest version of Firefox. But there is some confusion in your question about where you have installed Lynx - was it in an Ubuntu WSL distribution and you're wishing to restore it? See [link1](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-change-the-default-browser-in-ubuntu/) and [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16621/how-to-set-the-default-browser-from-the-command-line).

Comment: Can you add an example of how you're opening the paths you mean? What are the current contents of your `BROWSER` environment variable in wsl?

Comment: when I run `open .`, Lynx will open. I would like to restore the default WSL behavior and have it open File Explorer

Comment: @Cpt.Whale updated question for clarity, but `open`, `xdg-open` both seem to be pulling this new default from the same place

Comment: @Ramhound a text-based browser. https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lynx